# Azure AKS - cluster in failed state without any malfunction

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

My AKS cluster shows a flag which states that it is in a failed state, even if the cluster itself does not show any sign of malfunction.

I could create a new one, but avoiding it would be nice.

Could the matter be related to the use of a virtual node kublet? I used it when still was in preview.

EDIT: the problem is all there. There is no special action which triggers the error, it just appears fixed at the top of the overview page (and consequently I am stopped to perform specific actions).

Comment: Any more details? provide the error information is also helpful. Or what action cause the error?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score -1):

My Cluster was in Failed (Running) state. The following worked:

1. First, try to upgrade the cluster to the same version as it is today:

   $ az aks upgrade --name SHP-abc-K8s-c --resource-group shp-abc-rg-c --subscription "Production" --kubernetes-version 1.22.11 --yes
2. If the above doesnt help, update the Service Principle used by the cluster:

   $ az aks update-credentials --resource-group shp-abc-rg-c --name SHP-abc-K8s-c --reset-service-principal --service-principal "EXAMPLE-e11a-4494-b111-EXAMPLE" --client-secret "BlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlah"